# The HTTP client does not redirect in the integration tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, http-status-code-302

I have setup an integration test:

```
public class IntegrationTests
{
    private readonly TestServer _server;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public IntegrationTests()
    {
        _server = new TestServer(WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder().UseEnvironment("Development").UseStartup<Startup>())
        {
            PreserveExecutionContext = true,
        };
        _client = _server.CreateClient();
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task RunARoute()
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("/foo");

        Check.That(response.IsSuccessStatusCode).IsTrue();
    }
}
```

The startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddApplicationPart(typeof(HomeController).Assembly)
        .AddControllersAsServices()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

    services
        .ConfigureAll(Configuration) // Add the configuration sections
        .AddAllServices() // DI
        // Other:
        .AddAutoMapperProfiles(AutoMapperConfiguration.LoadConfig)
        .AddCacheHelper(e => {})
        .AddSession(opt => opt.Cookie.IsEssential = true);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection()
        .UseStaticFiles()
        .UseRouting()
        .UseCookiePolicy()
        .UseSession()
        .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                "default",
                "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
}
```

In the test method, the route that I call redirects to another route: `return RedirectToAction(nameof(Bar))`. I'd like to test that the page is correctly returned by the `Bar` method, but unfortunately, the `HttpClient` does not redirect the call: my test fails with a code `302`.

I've read on the Internet that this issue usually occurs when there is an attempt of a redirection from an HTTPS route to an HTTP one, but AFAIK, that's not the case here, since the test server creates a client with the base URL `http://localhost/`, and the redirection URL is relative (so no protocol specified).

How can I ensure that the client redirects the calls?

Comment: HTTP 302 is redirect code. Check the response header to assert that the redirect location is to the desired URL

Comment: I've verified that: the redirect location in the header is `"/bar"`

Comment: Then the code is behaving as expected.

Comment: @Nkosi How that? From what I've seen, by default the client follows the redirections

Comment: The client will not auto redirect. You would need to have access to the handler, which you cant since the test server creates the client

Comment: That is by design Check [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Hosting/TestHost/src/TestServer.cs) and you'll see it does not enable auto redirect

Answer (score 3):

That is by design. If you check the [`TestServer` source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Hosting/TestHost/src/TestServer.cs)

```
public HttpMessageHandler CreateHandler()
{
    var pathBase = BaseAddress == null ? PathString.Empty : PathString.FromUriComponent(BaseAddress);
    return new ClientHandler(pathBase, Application) { AllowSynchronousIO = AllowSynchronousIO, PreserveExecutionContext = PreserveExecutionContext };
}

public HttpClient CreateClient()
{
    return new HttpClient(CreateHandler()) { BaseAddress = BaseAddress };
}
```

you'll see it does not enable auto redirect feature which is actually a part of the `HttpClientHandler` normally used by default `HttpClient`.

`TestServer` however, uses a custom handler that does not auto redirect when creating the `HttpClient`. You would need to have access to the handler, which you can't since the test server creates the client internally.

Therefore the code as descried is behaving as expected.

The HTTP response status code 302 Found is a common way of performing a redirection.

Check the response header to assert that the redirect location header is to the desired URL in order to assert the expected behavior.

You can also consider manually calling the redirected URL to verify that it will return the HTTP response status code 200 OK

```
[Test]
public async Task RunARoute_Should_Redirect() {        
    _server.PreserveExecutionContext = true;
    var client = _server.CreateClient();
    var response = await _client.GetAsync("/foo");

    Check.That(response.StatusCode).IsEqualTo(HttpStatusCode.Found); //302 Found

    var redirectUrl = response.Headers.Location;

    //assert expected redirect URL
    //...

    response = await _client.GetAsync(redirectUrl);       

    Check.That(response.IsSuccessStatusCode).IsTrue(); //200 OK
}
```

Comment: That's a clever idea, unfortunately, this does not keep the `HttpContext.Session` between the calls.

Comment: Probably because Cookies would also need to be enabled to hold on to session data

Comment: @Boiethios consider setting `PreserveExecutionContext` to true

Comment: I've updated my code with the current configuration